# Externalize shell commands within Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How can I declutter my Jenkinsfile by moving all the shell commands to a separate file which can be referenced within the Jenkinsfile? Are there any best practices for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple options:

- `load` step to include another file from within the workspace
- [shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) to load them from a separate repo